# How do I get the ID of an added bookmarks folder?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, bookmarks

In the [documentation for `chrome.bookmarks`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/bookmarks.html), there's an example of how to use it. In the example, it creates a seperate folder for the extension:

```
chrome.bookmarks.create({'parentId': bookmarkBar.id,
                         'title': 'Extension bookmarks'},
                        function(newFolder) {
                            console.log("added folder: " + newFolder.title);
                        });
```

And then add a bookmark to that folder:

```
chrome.bookmarks.create({'parentId': extensionsFolderId,
                         'title': 'Extensions doc',
                         'url': 'http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions'});
```

My question is:

How do you get `extensionsFolderId` for the `parentId` parameter?

Comment: `newFolder.id` in the first callback

Comment: @方觉 Thanks. If only I could mark comments as correct answers!

Answer (score 1):

The callback function defined by `function(newFolder)` is called after the "Extension bookmarks" folder is created. Information about the created folder/bookmark, such as `id` and `title`, is available in the `BookmarkTreeNode` identified by `newFolder`.

```
function(newFolder) {
    console.log("added folder: " + newFolder.title + " with id: " + newFolder.id);
}
```

Since `create()` is an asynchronous call, you can't be sure when it'll be finished. You don't want to create the bookmark until after the folder is created, so call the second one from the callback function of the first one.

```
chrome.bookmarks.create({'parentId': bookmarkBar.id,
                         'title': 'Extension bookmarks'},
                        function(newFolder) {
                            console.log("added folder: " + newFolder.title);
                            createBookmark(newFolder.id);
                        });

function createBookmark(extensionsFolderId) {
    chrome.bookmarks.create({'parentId': extensionsFolderId,
                             'title': 'Extensions doc',
                             'url': 'http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions'});
}
```